# Distinguishing between two possibilities for the Jordan normal form of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, jordan-normal-form

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
2&2&0&0 \\ -2&-2&0&0 \\ 0&0&-1&1\\0&0&-1&1
\end{pmatrix}$. I noticed that $A^2=0_4$, and I deduced that the characteristic polynomial is $p(t)=t^4$ and the minimal polynomial is $m(t)=t^2$, so the largest order of the Jordan blocks relative to $\lambda_0=0$ is 2. Am I right that at this point I can only say that the JNF must either be $J_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$ or $J_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$ ?

Then I found that $\dim\ker A=2,$ thus $\operatorname{rk} A=2$ is the number of $1$'s in the JNF, which must then be $J_2$. Was there another way?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way I could suggest is, since $A$ is a block diagonal matrix, to compute the Jordan normal forms of the blocks $$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 \\ -2 & -2
\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
of $A$ which are both $$ J' = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
since $A_1, A_2$ are non-diagonalizable matrices with unique eigenvalue $0$.

Let $S_1, S_2$ be basis change matrices such that $S_i^{-1} A_i S_i = J'$ for $i=1,2$. Then we obtain $S^{-1} A S = J$ where
$$
\begin{align}
S &= \begin{pmatrix}
S_1 & 0 \\ 0 & S_2
\end{pmatrix} \quad \left(\Longrightarrow S^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
S_1^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & S_2^{-1}
\end{pmatrix} \right), \\
A &= \begin{pmatrix}
A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & A_2
\end{pmatrix}
 \text{ and } \\
J &= \begin{pmatrix}
J' & 0 \\ 0 & J'
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
$$
our desired Jordan normal form of $A$.